# How can I assign correct year to date string based on if date has passed in the current year?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

How can I add year to a vector of dates that is missing year, assigning next year if the date has already passed this year, or this year if upcoming in this year?

Sample data:

```
datevec <- c("March 15 2:00 PM","January 7 3:00 PM","November 4 9:00 AM", "August 5 10:00AM", "February 6 10:00PM","December 5 6:00 AM")
```

Desired return year (based on question asked Sept 6 2023):

```
desired_years <- c("2024","2024","2023","2024","2024","2023")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the strings todate-time objects using `strptime`. This will assume the current year. Then test if the result is later than `Sys.time()`, which allows you to `ifelse` 2023 / 2024

```r
ifelse(strptime(datevec, "%B %d %H:%M %p") > Sys.time(), "2023", "2024")
#> [1] "2024" "2024" "2023" "2024" "2024" "2023"
```

Comment: @MrFlick unsure. Is `Sys.time()` better?

Comment: The `ifelse(strptime(` runs fine on `R-4.2.1` linux., using `Sys.time()`, missed the Date( edit.

Answer (score 3):

Form the POSIXct date/times, `tt`, and then for those that are greater than now add 1 year to them.  Finally take the year.

```
library(lubridate)
 
datevec <- c("March 15 2:00 PM","January 7 3:00 PM","November 4 9:00 AM", 
  "August 5 10:00AM", "February 6 10:00PM","December 5 6:00 AM")
 
Now <- now()
tt <- ymd_hm(paste(year(Now), datevec))
datetimes <- tt + years(tt > Now); datetimes
## [1] "2023-03-15 14:00:00 UTC" "2023-01-07 15:00:00 UTC"
## [3] "2024-11-04 09:00:00 UTC" "2023-08-05 10:00:00 UTC"
## [5] "2023-02-06 22:00:00 UTC" "2024-12-05 06:00:00 UTC"

yr <- year(datetimes); yr
## [1] 2023 2023 2024 2023 2023 2024
```

If you don't need the datetimes then replace the last two lines with

```
yr2 <- year(tt) + (tt > Now); yr2
## [1] 2023 2023 2024 2023 2023 2024
```